# How to multiply Python Xarray Datasets?

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I am reading multiple netCDF formatted data files (WRF model output files) using `xarray.open_mfdataset()` function. I am reading and destaggering various variables such as Variable `QVAPOR`, `U` & `V` resp. I am using the  following code for reading netCDF variables and computing resultant variable `UQ`.

```
import xarray as xr

def desta_var(pp,var):
    flnm = xr.open_mfdataset(pp)
    if var=="U":
        U1 = (flnm.variables[var])
        U = 0.5*(U1[:,:,:,0:-1] + U1[:,:,:,1:] )
        del U1
        return U
    elif var=="V":
        V1 = (flnm.variables[var])
        V=0.5*(V1[:,:,0:-1,:] + V1[:,:,1:,:])
        del V1
        return V
    else:
        W1 = (flnm.variables[var])
        W=0.5*(W1[:,0:-1,:,:] + W1[:,1:,:,:])
        del W1
        return W

 U=desta_var('./WRF_3D_2005_*.nc','U')
 V=desta_var('./WRF_3D_2005_*.nc','V')

 flnm=xr.open_mfdataset('./WRF_3D_2005_*.nc')

 QV = flnm.QVAPOR
 UQ = U*QV
```

**Dimension and shape of variables obtained using above code:**

The dimensions of wind variables Ex. `U` and its shape is

> Times, lev, y, x_2 and it's shape is (1186, lev: 36, y: 699, x_2: 639)

The dimensions of Moisture variables Ex. `QVAPOR` and its shape is

> Times, lev, y, x and it's shape is (1186, lev: 36, y: 699, x: 639)

After multiplying `U` and `QVAPOR` ; I compute `UQ=U*QVAPOR`. The dimension and shape of `UQ` is

> Times, lev, y, x_2, x and shape is (Times: 1186, lev: 36, y: 699, x_2: 639, x: 639)

So the problem is as follows:

I am not able to get the dimensions correct. The correct dimensions of `UQ` should be `Times, lev, y, x`. Could anybody help me how to multiply xarray Datasets with different dimension names.
I am not sure why do I get UQ variable with 5 dimension while U and QVAPOR are 4 dimension each.

Comment: It is hard to tell where things are going wrong for you since we can't see what the dimensions of either U or QV are. I'd suggest editing your question with a Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @jhamman .. thank you for the suggestions. I have made the changes in the questions. I had tried to keep the question as short as I could.

Answer (score 9):

Unlike NumPy, Xarray matches up array dimensions by *name*, not position.

It loops over dimensions with different names in arithmetic, and your DataArray objects have different dimensions: [Times, lev, y, x_2] and [Times, lev, y, x].

The simple fix is to rename `x_2` -> `x` on the first array before multiplying them together, e.g,. `U.rename({'x_2': 'x'}) * QVAPOR`.

(Note that you may also need to align or *reindex* the coordinate values along `x_2` if they don't exactly match those along `x`. Something like `U.rename({'x_2': 'x'}).reindex(x=QVAPOR.x, method='nearest', tolerance=123)` should do the trick.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply @shoyer. Your solution worked. I just had to tweak little bit with variables. I had used the following code for multiplication.

`UQ1=flnm.QVAPOR.rename({'x': 'x_2'}) * U`

After this I had renamed the output.

`UQ1.rename({'x_2':'x'})`

So the dimensions of the output variable is now:
`(Times: 1186, lev: 36, y: 699, x: 639)`