# What is the behaviour of xarray when multiplying data arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, geospatial, python-xarray

I would like to multiply two data arrays of same dimensions:

```py
print(data1)
<xarray.DataArray 'var' (lat: 2160, lon: 4320)>
[9331200 values with dtype=int8]
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 -180.0 -179.9 -179.8 -179.7 ... 179.8 179.9 180.0
  * lat      (lat) float64 89.96 89.88 89.79 89.71 ... -89.79 -89.88 -89.96

print(data2)
<xarray.DataArray 'var' (lat: 2160, lon: 4320)>
[9331200 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 -180.0 -179.9 -179.8 -179.7 ... 179.8 179.9 180.0
  * lat      (lat) float64 89.96 89.88 89.79 89.71 ... -89.79 -89.87 -89.96
```

`data1 * data2` returns this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot apply_along_axis when any iteration dimensions are 0
```

Note that following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186609/how-to-multiply-python-xarray-datasets), I made sure to have consistent dimensions and re-indexed both data arrays.

Since both arrays have different `dtype`, I have tried `data1.astype(np.float64) * data2`, but that returned the same error.

On the other hand, this returned an empty array:

```py
data3 = data1.astype(np.float64) * data2.astype(np.float64)

print(data3)
<xarray.DataArray 'var' (lat: 0, lon: 0)>
array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=float64)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 
  * lat      (lat) float64
```

The only way I found to achieve this multiplication was to get the underlying np data:

```py
data3 = data1.data * data2.data
```

Although this works for my need, I am still curious to understand why the pure xarray method fails. Can anyone inform me or point me towards a part of the documentation I might have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, there was a slight difference in the coordinates of my two data arrays, apparently due to floating point precision (thanks to [these guys](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/7896)). You can whether coordinates of both data arrays are correct with:

```py
import xarray as xr 

xr.testing.assert_equal(data1.lon, data2.lon)
xr.testing.assert_equal(data1.lat, data2.lat)
```

In case one is sure the coordinates should align, one option is to manually correct the coordinates:

```py
data1['lon'] = data2['lon']
data1['lat'] = data2['lat']
```

Then the multiplication works without problem.